# jasypt: Force same result when encrypting

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I am just wondering whether it's possible to force an encryptor to always return the same encrypted value for the same input.

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptorencryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPassword("My password");
encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");

String value1 = encryptor.encrypt("encryptme")
String value2 = encryptor.encrypt("encryptme")
String value3 = encryptor.encrypt("encryptSomethingElse")

assertEquals(value1,value2);
assertNotEquals(value1,value3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation of `StandardPBEStringEncryptor`](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html) mentions,

> If a random salt generator is used, two encryption results for the
>   same message will always be different (except in the case of random
>   salt coincidence).

And a random salt generator is indeed the default if you don't explicitly set a salt generator.

For the purpose of a unit test, you could set a salt generator that returns the same salt for the same input (or always returns the same salt), like `ZeroSaltGenerator`, using `encryptor.setSaltGenerator(mySaltGenerator);`

However make sure that this doesn't seep into your real code - only do that for testing.

Comment: It's working now using a FixedStringSaltGenerator:

    FixedStringSaltGenerator fixedSaltGenerator = new FixedStringSaltGenerator();
    fixedSaltGenerator.setSalt("My salt!");
    encryptor.setSaltGenerator(fixedSaltGenerator);